# Kendo-ui JQuery not autostarting conversation with microsoft botframework

Tags: kendo-ui, botframework

I want to use the Kendo-UI for JQuery as the front end for my bot.

[This](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/chat/index) demo is what I'm trying to use. When you start the demo the bot automaticly greets you, but when I change the secret to mine it doesn't start the conversation. With my secret it just waits for user input before starting. When I test my bot with the bot framework emulator it does send a message when connecting.

I do not know why this happens. I did not change any code of the kendo demo, which makes me think that the problem lies with my bot framework. On the other hand the emulator does give me the desired outcome. I'm at a loss on how to solve my issue.

Below is the onMembersAddedAsync function of MyBot.cs, which to my understanding should send the greeting message when a new client connects.

```
 protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            foreach (var member in membersAdded)
            {
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    //sends some messages to welcome the user + suggestedactions
                    await WelcomeNewUser(turnContext, cancellationToken); 
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a possible solution, instead of using the `OnMembersAddedAsync` function I send the welcome message from `OnTurnAsync`. I deleted the `OnMembersAddedAsync` because it doesn't do anything anymore.

```
 public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);


            if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                // Save any state changes that might have occured during the turn.
                await ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
                await UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                // Send an initial welcome message
                if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate && turnContext.Activity.MembersAdded.FirstOrDefault()?.Id == turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    await WelcomeNewUser(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }
```